# Product Variation is not showing on the cart page

Tags: woocommerce, product-variations

After updating WooCommerce 2.6.4 into WooCommerce 3.0.+, some of the product variations are not showing on the cart page. But some product variation is showing on the cart page. My WordPress version is 4.7.5 and WooCommerce version is 3.0.7.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved, add this to child theme `function.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: Was looking for the solution to get attribure in cart. The solution works for Woocommerce Version 3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Override the cart.php in your child theme.. Issue must be the old cart.php template on your child theme.

replace this

```
if (!$_product->is_visible()) {
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . ' ';
} else {
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '%s', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
}

// Meta data
echo WC()->cart->get_item_data($cart_item);

// Backorder notification
if ($_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder($cart_item['quantity'])) {
echo '' . esc_html__('Available on backorder', 'woocommerce') . '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_false' );
```

It works fine at here as well